# json_decode fails with error code 4 when file has two distinct json elements

Tags: php, json

```
{
  "file": 1, 
  "format": 1
}
{
  "info_sent": 0.0, 
  "lsd": true, 
  "send_info": false
}
```

when the file is arranged like this, `json_decode` returns a syntax error. this is the configuration file for deluge by the way.

Comment: If you pass your JSON file through any JSON validator, for instance http://jsonlint.com/, you'd notice that the format is incorrect.

Comment: @sk099, did you find an answer to the question? It would be great if you could comment and/or accept an answer.

Comment: adding a comma between the two elements didn't help. the solution was some hacky regex bs that captured the first element, removed it, then decoded the remaining json.

Comment: Of course only ading a comma does not help. Did you try my solution? What was the output?

Answer (score 0):

JSON requires a comma between the two elements, and then it should be wrapped as an array.

Like this:

```
[{
  "file": 1, 
  "format": 1
},
{
  "info_sent": 0.0, 
  "lsd": true, 
  "send_info": false
}]
```

To use the original format, create a loop where you decode each element separately and push the resulting object into an array.

Assuming your file has one line per JSON element, your code could look like this:

```
$result = [];
foreach(file('myfile.txt') as $line) {
    $result[] = json_decode($line);
}
```

If your file is arranged differently (one JSON occupying more than one line), you'll have to change the above code. All depends on the format of the file...